# Retrieve data for a node in xml using LINQ and where clause

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>   
<departments>  
  <department id="1">  
    <name>Mens Shirts</name>   
    <Products>  
      <Product>Mens Classic White</Product>   
      <Product>Mens Full whites</Product>   
    </Products>  
  </department>  
  <department id="2">  
    <name>Mens Trousers</name>   
    <Products>  
      <Product>Mens Formal Blacks</Product>   
      <Product>Mens Black Jeans</Product>   
    </Products>  
  </department>  
</departments>
```

How can I get the department name for a particular product using LINQ? eg: find dept for product = "Mens Classic White"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XDocument class to get the information from your file.

```
var productName = "Mens Classic White";

XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(@"C:\xmlFile.xml");
var q = doc.Elements("departments")
    .Where(parent => parent.Elements(productName)
    .Any(child => child.Elements("department").Any()));
```